# Terraform Not Recognising AWS ASG Target Tracking Scaling Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, autoscaling

I am attempting to deploy an ECS Fargate configuration within an ASG via terraform templates. As far as I am aware, AWS ASG recognises two approaches for scaling:

1. Target Tracking Scaling Policies: These automatically adjust the number of scalable targets as required to keep the metric you selected at your chosen target value.
2. Step Scaling Policies: These increase or decrease the current capacity of your resource based on a set of scaling adjustments, known as step adjustments, which vary based on the size of the alarm breach.

However when attempting to configure my ASG resource to scale based on the following code, using a target tracking with average CPU utilisation as its metric:

```
resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "ecs_target" {
  service_namespace  = "ecs"
  resource_id        = "service/${var.cluster_name}/${var.service_name}"
  scalable_dimension = "ecs:service:DesiredCount"
  min_capacity       = 1
  max_capacity       = 10
}

resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "ecs_cpu_policy" {
  name               = "cpu-scaling"
  service_namespace  = aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target.service_namespace
  resource_id        = aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target.resource_id
  scalable_dimension = aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target.scalable_dimension

  target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration {
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization"
    }

    target_value       = 50.0 
    scale_in_cooldown  = 300
    scale_out_cooldown = 300
  }
}
```

I receive the following error on terraform apply:

```
│ Error: creating Application Auto Scaling Policy (cpu-scaling): ValidationException: StepScaling policy configuration must be specified
```

And sure enough, changing to use a step scaling policy does allow me to deploy. Why is one approach successful and the other not recognised by AWS through Terraform?

Answer (score 2):

Reading the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/appautoscaling_policy) for this resource, the example I see has a `policy_type` defined

```
resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "dynamodb_table_read_policy" {
  ...
  policy_type        = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  ...
  target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration {
```

And it looks like the [default policy_type](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/9e0b8b0de458a6bc0dfe432cab4d630c475716ab/internal/service/appautoscaling/policy.go#L65) is `StepScaling`

So you should probably do

```
resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "ecs_cpu_policy" {
  name               = "cpu-scaling"
  policy_type        = "TargetTrackingScaling"
  service_namespace  = aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target.service_namespace
  resource_id        = aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target.resource_id
  scalable_dimension = aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target.scalable_dimension

  target_tracking_scaling_policy_configuration {
    predefined_metric_specification {
      predefined_metric_type = "ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization"
    }

    target_value       = 50.0 
    scale_in_cooldown  = 300
    scale_out_cooldown = 300
  }
}
```